# Changing class attribute of an element - Django forms

Tags: django, django-templates

I have registration form and I am using Django-registration. Now, I need to add css class to each field. Also, if there are validation errors, then css class should be different for the fields which have error. How can I achieve this?

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
"""
Form for registering a new user account.

Validates that the requested username is not already in use, and
requires the password to be entered twice to catch typos.

Subclasses should feel free to add any additional validation they
need, but should avoid defining a ``save()`` method -- the actual
saving of collected user data is delegated to the active
registration backend.

"""
error_css_class = 'error'
required_css_class='wanted'

email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(maxlength=75)),
                         label=_("Email address"))
password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False),
                            label=_("Password"))
password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False),
                            label=_("Password (again)"))
```

In html template, I am doing

```
<div class="row">
<label for="id_email"><span>*</span> Email Address:</label>
{{ form.email }}
</div>
```

**Note** Eventually, I ended up using widget_tweaks, which allowed me to do

```
{{form.email|add_class:"blink"|add_error_class:"error"}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target form fields without adding a class to each field. Just use CSS rules similar to the following, depending on whether you are rendering the form using `as_table` (the default for the form's unicode method), `as_ul` or `as_p`.

```
form tr {...}
form li {...}
form p  {...}
```

For required fields and fields with errors, you can define `required_css_class` and `error_css_class` attributes respectively for a form.

```
class ContactForm(Form):
    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required'
```

For more information see the docs for [*Styling required or erroneous form rows*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#styling-required-or-erroneous-form-rows).

If you manually render the form fields in your template, you can access the field's css classes using the [`css_classes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.css_classes) method.

```
<div class="row {{ form.email.css_classes }}">
<label for="id_email"><span>*</span> Email Address:</label>
{{ form.email }}
</div>
```

Comment: +1. People seem to forget the *cascading* part of Cascading Style Sheets.

Comment: I added both the attributes but it is not working. Fields are defined like email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(maxlength=75)),
                             label=_("Email address"))

Comment: If it's not working, please update your question with your form, your template, and the output you are getting.

Comment: Ah, you're rendering the fields by hand in the template. In that case, you can use the bound field's `css_classes` method. I've updated my answer with an example.